# fancybox image not loading in moderna html theme development project

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to converting Moderna HTML template to WordPress theme. But the fancy-box image not working properly when I tried to post image with custom post (portfolio) from back end.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4 class="heading">Recent Works</h4>
    <div class="row">
     <section id="projects">
     <ul id="thumbs" class="portfolio">
     
   <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>  
  <?php $portfolio_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
     
           <?php 
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' =>4,'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'DEC' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                         
                            <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
      <li class="col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
                            <div class="item-thumbs">
                                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Work 1" href="<?php echo $portfolio_thumb[0]; ?>">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-image'); ?>
                            </div>
      </li>
                         
                   <?php endwhile;   ?>
    
      <!-- End Item Project -->
     </ul>
     </section>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the theme details--http://bootstraptaste.com/free-bootstrap-template-corporate-moderna/

Please help me for this purpose.

Comment: How does it "not work properly"? Any error?

Comment: Actually not showing any error but when I click on the image it is not showing the popup properly. It does not show the full image in the popup and show ''Work 1 undefined''. I am sending a Dropbox link with full theme details.

Comment: What about the href values for the links? Are they correct?

Comment: http://we.tl/H7sGIe3BEh

Comment: Do you need any other information? I sent you a screenshot and the full theme files. Please help me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the thumb URL outside of the posts loop. Considering your page doesn't have a thumbnail, `has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )` will return false then `$portfolio_thumb` will not be set and `$portfolio_thumb[0]` will echo "undefined" as you experienced. What you need is to move the post thumbnail call inside the loop:

```
<ul id="thumbs" class="portfolio">
    <?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' =>4,'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'DEC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
            $portfolio_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
        else:
            continue;
        endif; ?>
        <li class="col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
            <div class="item-thumbs">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Work 1" href="<?php echo $portfolio_thumb[0]; ?>">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-image'); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;   ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes I got it . Thank you very much :)